# coin package wilcox.test function returns neither error nor result

Tags: r

My `mat` data matrix is like:

```
V3      V7    
ASD     4.4   
ASD     4.3
control 4.3
```

I use following codes:

```
mat <- transform(mat, V3 = factor(V3))
wilcox_test(V7 ~ V3, data =mat, distribution = "exact")
```

But I get neither error nor results:

[image]

When I delete `"distribution"`,the function works well:

[image]

Although this test is obviously meaningless, I want it for consistency with other tests in our work (all using permutation tests), so I wish to keep `"distribution=exact"`. Can anybody find out what is going wrong and how to fix it?Thanks!

Edit:I try to save and export the result as:

```
pdis=wilcox_test(V7 ~ V3, data =mat, distribution = “exact”)
pdis
summary(pdis)
```

But i get"Can't find the boject pdis".Did i make a mistake?

Comment: Looks like you aren’t saving the result of wilcox_test to a variable. If you are sourcing the entire script, it will run without producing visible output.

Comment: I'm worried about the quotation marks in your screenshot, which look like "smart" or "fancy" quotes.  When I input your data and run `wilcox_test(V7 ~ V3, data =mat, distribution = "exact")` I get a reasonable answer `Z = 0.70711, p-value = 1` ...

Comment: Thos look like "smart-quotes". Might cause further errors.

Answer (score 0):

The `coin::wilcox_test` function will accept a distribution parameter with an argument of "exact".

```
library(coin)
mat <- read.table(text="V3      V7    
ASD     4.4   
ASD     4.3
control 4.3",header=TRUE)

mat <- within(mat, V3 = factor(V3))

wilcox_test(V7 ~ V3, data =mat, distribution = "exact")
#------

    Exact Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney Test

data:  V7 by V3 (ASD, control)
Z = 0.70711, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0
```

Not clear what your problem might be:

```
>  pdis <- wilcox_test(V7 ~ V3, data =mat, distribution = "exact")
> summary(pdis)
                Length                  Class                   Mode 
                     1 ScalarIndependenceTest                     S4
```

Perhaps you really do have an R data.matrix but in that case, you cannot have a factor column. R matrices do not allow attributes, and factors get coerced to integers.